# Effect of renaming table column on explain/execution plans

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, explain, sql-execution-plan

I have a table with 300+ columns and hundreds of thousands of records. I need to re-name one of the existing columns.

Is there anything that I need to be worried about? Will this operation have any effect on the explain plans etc ?

Notes:

1. I am working on a live production database on Oracle 11g.
2. This column is not being used currently. It's not populated for any of the rows and I am 100% sure none of the existing queries refer to this column.

Comment: OK.  So you are absolutely certain that no one is doing a `SELECT *` against the table?

Comment: Yes. There are no select * against the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "working on a live production database" means that you are going to try to do this without testing in lower environments while people are working, I would strongly caution against that plan.

Existing query plans that involve the table you're doing DDL on will be invalidated so those queries will need to be hard parsed again.  That can easily be an expensive operation if there are large numbers of such queries.  It is certainly possible that some query plans will change because something else has changed (i.e. statistics are different, settings are different, bind variables are different, etc.)  They won't change because of the column name change but the column name change may result in changed plans.

Any queries that you're executing will, obviously, need to use the new name as soon as you rename the column.  That generally means that you need to do a coordinated release where you modify the code (including stored procedures) as well as the column name.  That, in turn, generally implies that you're doing this as part of a build that includes at least a bit of downtime.  You probably could, if you have the enterprise edition, do edition-based redefinition without downtime but that adds complexity to the process and is something that you would absolutely need to test thoroughly before implementing it in prod.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Justin. I am definitely planning to do this in lower environments first and then move it into production with a build which would involve some downtime.

Comment: I have added some additional notes. Does that make any difference to your answer.

Comment: @Curious - No change.  If you really have no queries that reference that column, including nothing that does a `SELECT *`, then you won't have any queries to modify.  Personally, I'd still assume that anything that operates against the table will need to be tested in the lower environments just to confirm that everything is still working.